# Nested table with table-layout: fixed affecting parent table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm giving my *nested* table (within a `<td>` element) the style `table-layout: fixed`. For some reason, this is affecting my *parent* table as well:

[image: Screenshot without table-layout: fixed]

[image: Screenshot with table-layout: fixed]

Demo:

```js
document.getElementById('set-fixed').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = (
    document.getElementById('nested').classList.toggle('fixed')
    ? 'fixed'
    : 'not fixed'
  )
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}

table.fixed {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<p>Set nested table's style <code>table-layout: fixed</code>: <button id="set-fixed">Toggle</button> (current: <span id='result'>not fixed</span>)</p>
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <table id='nested' width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td>Foo</td>
          <td>Baaaaaaar!</td>
          <td>Baz</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Taco</td>
    <td>Beautiful, cheesy, and delicious.</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Marshmallow</td>
    <td>Too sweet for my tastes!</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is this a bug with Firefox, or intentional (according to the relevant official spec)? What can I do to make my nested table's layout fixed without affecting my parent table?

Comment: I can reproduce what you describe in Firefox but not Chrome.

Comment: Likely a bug with Firefox, then. For reference, I'm running Firefox 52.3.0 (ESR).

Comment: I tried running this on Safari 11 (iOS); it works as one would expect. So this is almost definitely a bug in Firefox. @showdev, thanks for trying this on a non-Firefox browser!

Comment: I have the same issue in Firefox 57.